# Taking difference between two cells in python for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, openpyxl

what i'm trying to do is finding a difference between B201 and B52 cell, and put the answer in D52 cell excel. Then, I want to repeat the subtraction formula up to value1 cell which can be any row. value that I have in b column is timestamp. That's why i used datetime.

```
filename1 ="C:\\Users\\hhh.xlsx"
wb2 = xl.load_workbook(filename1)
ws2 = wb2.active
for i in range(52,value1) and j in range (201, int(value2)):
    ws2.cell(row=i, column=4).value = datetime.datetime(float(ws2.cell(row=j, column=2).value)) -  datetime.datetime(float(ws2.cell(row=i, column=2).value))
```

can someone please correct me? Thanks in advance

Comment: What is `value2`?

Comment: This is tagged as pandas, but you are not using pandas in this example. If you were to use pandas though, then I would consider using `.shift()` rather than looping. For example: `df['Col D'] = df['Col B'] - df.shift(149)['Col B']`

Answer (score 0):

Just use one loop that goes from `0` to `value1`, and add that to `52` and `201` to get the corresponding rows that should be substracted.

```
for n in range(value1):
    i = 52 + n
    j = 201 + n
    cell1 = ws2.cell(row=j, column=2).value
    cell2 = ws2.cell(row=i, column=2).value
    if cell1 and cell2: # Make sure both cells are filled in
        ws2.cell(row=i, column=4).value = float(cell1) -  float(cell2)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. if i run the above code, i get "TypeError: integer argument expected, got float". if i remove the datetime.datetime and use just the float, i get "TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'NoneType'" .please help me

Comment: That's a completely unrelated problem, it has nothing to do with the looping.

Comment: Are you sure all the cells are filled in? If not, you need to check before trying to use them.

Comment: I've updated the answer to add the check and remove the inappropriate `datetime` calls.